# Elasticsearch query with Must (and) Should (or) not producing desired results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to perform a query  of X AND (y OR z)
I need to get all the sold properties that the agent was either the listing agent or the selling agent.

With only the bool must I get 9324 results. When I add the bool should, I get the same result set of 9324. The agent with the ID of 140699 should have only about 100 results. I've also tried a bool filter with no success. When replacing the should with a filter, the result is like another bool must, and I only get results where the agent was the listing agent AND the selling agent

```html
GET /property/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "statusCatID": {
              "value": "Sold"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "closingDate": {
              "gte": "now-3M"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "listAgent1": {
              "value": 140699
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "sellingAgent1": {
              "value": 140699
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 300
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your notation you are performing a query like this:

```
(statuscatid:sold AND closingDate:now-3M OR listAgent1:140699 OR sellingAgent1:140699)
```

I suggest you to read [this official blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/lost-in-translation-boolean-operations-and-filters-in-the-bool-query) to understand better the bool queries in elastic. If you want a query like this:

```
(statuscatid:sold AND closingDate:now-3M) AND (listAgent1:140699 OR sellingAgent1:140699)
```

You should write it in this way:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "statusCatId": "sold"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "closingDate": "now-3M"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "listAgent1": 140699
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "sellingAgent1": 140699
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 300
}
```